# Why wont this dropdownlistfor selected value work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these properties in my ViewModel:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Make is required")]
 public int CarOneMakeId { get; set; }
 public SelectList CarOneMakes { get; set; }
```

This code in my constructor:

```
CarOneMakes = new SelectList(carMakes, "Key", "Value", chosenMakes[0].Value);
```

I can see clearly when I hover over CarOneMakes in debug that the selected value HAS been given. Finally I have this in my View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarOneMakeId, Model.CarOneMakes, "Select Makes", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For some reason I can't get the default value to be selected. I know it has the correct value.

I have tried ensuring the first parameter of the DropDownListFor is an id, ensuring I have no conflicting names, and even casting as a selectlist which some people have done and that also did nothing:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarOneMakeId, ((SelectList)Model.CarOneMakes), "Select Makes", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: Adding the last parameter in the `SelectList` constructor (`chosenMakes[0].Value`) is pointless - its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` - you need to set the value of `CarOneMakeId` (your binding to a property and its the value of the property which determines what is selected)

Comment: That was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your selected Id to `m.CarOneMakeId` that's how `DropDownListFor` works.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you please show me with code?

Comment: No worries, the other comment helped me figure it out! thanks